# Detecting if section is currently visible on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do a sort of navigation based on current section.

My code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    'use strict';

    function setTitle(title) {
        $('.overlay').text(title);
    }

    function removeTitle() {
        $('.overlay').text('');
    }

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        let windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            sections = $('section[data-title]');

        sections.each(function() {
            let thisStart = $(this).offset().top,
                thisHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true),
                thisTitle = $(this).attr('data-title'),
                thisEnd = thisHeight + thisStart;

            console.log(`start: ${thisStart}, end: ${thisEnd}, scroll: ${windowScroll}`);

            if(windowScroll >= thisStart && windowScroll < thisEnd) {
                setTitle(thisTitle);
            } else {
                removeTitle();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<section class="section section-first"></section>
<section class="section section-what" data-title="First">
</section>
<section class="section section-cv" data-title="Secound">
</section>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Unfortunately, it works only with last `.section`. What can I do?

Please refer to my CodePen to see what I mean exactly: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/Xmovwq

Comment: You should be more exact into what the problem is. What is observed behavior vs what is the expected behavior?

Comment: Working fine if you remove the `else` statement. Second section is currently rewriting the text of the other.

Comment: If you remove the else, the title will never get removed.

Comment: Never is a big word, I wasn't suggesting to not use it *at all*. Just that it's basically fine but not noticably so. Interrupting the loop has it's disadvantage as well. I'd go for storing any values in an array myself.

Answer (score 2):

Add `return false;` here:

```
if(windowScroll >= thisStart && windowScroll < thisEnd) {
    setTitle(thisTitle);
    return false;        // <- add this
} else {
    removeTitle();
}
```

That will break out of the `each` method and prevent the title from being removed once it's been set.

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOoXXd)